# jquery fadeOut only works once when i make an angular call?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slim

I know their is alot of questions similar to this but i will be real specific. My jquery script only works once and after that i get this error

`angular.min.js:108 DELETE http://localhost:8080/todo/20 500 (Internal Server Error)`

yet it deletes my post on refresh. So the angular script is working, so im guessing its my jquery script

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('john',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location){

$scope.deleteTask = function(id){

    $http.delete('/todo/' + id).then(function(data, response, status, headers, config){
            $http.delete('/todo/' + id);
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('/');
            console.log("it deleted");
        }, function(rejection){
            console.log("some error");
        });
    }


$scope.addTask = function(taskdata){


    $http.post('/todo', taskdata).then(function(response){
        // taskdata.task = '';
        console.log("it works");
    }, function(rejection){
        console.log("it didn't work");
    });


}


});
    $('#disappear').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#gone').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });



    });
```

Here is the html code of it

```
<div id="gone" class="myl" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li><h4>{{ task.task}}</h4></li>
    <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.created_at |date("m/d/Y")}}</small></br>

<button id="disappear" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask({{task.id}})">Delete</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Jquery tag id selector #disappear #gone, JQuery Events get attached only once. Which means it will only work once.

Perform fadeOut when the $http.delete call succeeds:

```
$http.delete('/todo/' + id).then(function(data, response, status, headers, config){
  $( 'task' + id ).fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
```

For this to work, in our HTML we need to assign a unique id to our task div:

```
<div id="task{{task.id}}" class="myl" ng-controller="myCtrl">...
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but it doesn't fade out but i does delete

Comment: here is the error i get `angular.js:12587 DELETE http://localhost:8080/todos 405 (Method Not Allowed)` but i deletes the task though but doesn't fade out

Comment: Server is not returning 200 that's why it's not fading out. Server might have a Middleware handling requests.

Comment: what do you think i should do